# Ubuntu 12.04: mouse and wireless not working on startup

Tags: 12.04, boot, wireless, mouse, touchpad

yesterday everything worked fine but today both the mouse/touchpad and the wireless card are not working after boot.

The mouse starts to work after a `sudo modprobe psmouse` but i don't know what to do with  the wireless card and i don't know the source of the problem. No updates have been installed.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. And sudo modprobe psmouse also works for the mouse. So it appears not to be isolated. I just recently ran update manager, so I'm guessing some update broke them.

Answer (score 0):

**Update modules File**

To fix this you'll need to update /etc/modules with your touchpad and wireless modules:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modules
```

Add the following lines to the end of the file:

```
psmouse
<your wifi module>
```

Then reboot to see if it worked. If you don't know your wifi module...

**Find Your Wifi Module**

My wifi module is *iwlwifi* . To figure that out, here's what I did.

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

This lists your network hardware, and some additional details. You'll have to wait a few seconds before you get any output. For my adapter I noticed near the top it was marked as "UNCLAIMED". If yours isn't marked as unclaimed, perhaps something else is up.

I then searched on-line for my product (Centrino Advanced-N 6200) and *modprobe* to figure out what module I needed to load. When you find this test it out with `sudo modeprobe <your module>`.

If your wireless still isn't working run `sudo lshw -C network` again. If your network adapter is now "DISABLED" you just need to enable it. For me I hit +F11.

Now that you've figured out your wireless adapter module, update /etc/modules and reboot.

Comment: Hmm. I just discovered my sound isn't working either. I ran `sudo lshw | grep UNCLAIMED` and it looks like I'm missing a lot of drivers. There's got to be a solution to properly rebuild the modules file.